# How to store validation rules in appconstants in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to store business validation rules objects in a static file(constants.ts) so I can reference the messages in my validation function. If the validation fails, I have to return the following three properties which are in my :

```
status:boolean
errorMessage:string
errorMeaning:string
errorNo:number
errorDescription: string
```

The validation function is :

```
constructor() {
 this.upval = new UploadValidationModel();
}

validateFileHeaderColumns(data: any ): UploadValidationModel {
if (data[1].length !== 6) {
  this.upval.status = false;
  this.upval.errorMessage = 'Incorrect number of fields';
  this.upval.errorFix = 'Check that Row 1 has seven (7) fields';
  return this.upval;
}
```

}

so rather than hardcoding it here, is there a way I can have these values as constants in a file then inject them?
I have tried adding a uploadvalidation.ts file with the following code but I am not sure how I can get these values. There could also be multiple rules so I need an array of objects in this  file.

```
export const UploadValidationInvalidHeader
{
 { "status" : false,
   "errorMessage": 'Incorrect number of fields',
   "errorMeaning": 'Fix it',
   "errorNo":number
   "errorDescription": string
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to import modules in typescript? It should be as simple as `import { UploadValidationInvalidHeader } from './constants.ts'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all your validation error results in one object, where the business rule name is the key, like so

```
export const validationResult:ValdationResultMapType {
UploadValidationInvalidHeader: { 
   "status" : false,
   "errorMessage": 'Incorrect number of fields',
   "errorMeaning": 'Fix it',
   "errorNo": 1234,
   "errorDescription": 'Check that Row 1 has seven (7) fields',
  }
}
```

and then, when a validation fails, spread the details on your validation result

```
validateFileHeaderColumns(data: any ): UploadValidationModel {
if (data[1].length !== 6) {
  this.upval = {...validationResult.UploadValidationInvalidHeader};
  return this.upval;
}
```